# docker-compose subfolders doesn't appear in volume folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest
RUN mkdir /app/
RUN mkdir /app/subfolder1
RUN mkdir /app/subfolder2
VOLUME /app/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  my_test:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
```

I watched (in mysql Dockerfile) how the database mysql files are shared, I decided to do the same. I expect that the first time start **docker-compose up**, two subfolders from outside will be created in the **/app** folder. But during running **docker-compose up**, only one folder **/app** is created without subfolders inside. What am I doing wrong?

Please tell me how can I achieve the same behavior as with the MySQL container, when at the first start my external folder is filled with files and folders, and then it’s just used:

```
version: '3'
services:
   mysql:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
        - ./data/db:/var/lib/mysql
```

Example above works, but my first example doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysql` image has an [involved entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/bc6e37a2bed792b1c4fc6ab1ec3ce316e6a5f061/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh) that does the first-time setup.  That specifically checks to see whether the data directory exists or not:

```sh
if [ -d "$DATADIR/mysql" ]; then
    DATABASE_ALREADY_EXISTS='true'
fi
if [ -z "$DATABASE_ALREADY_EXISTS" ]; then
    docker_init_database_dir "$@"
    ...
fi
```

Note that this does not rely on any built-in Docker functionality, and does not copy any content out of the original image; it runs a fairly involved sequence of steps to populate the initial database setup, configure users, and run the contents in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory.

If you want to copy some sort of seed data into a mounted volume, your container generally needs to handle this itself.  You could write an entrypoint script like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# If the data directory doesn't have content, copy it
if ! [ -d /data/content ]; then
  cp -a /app/data/content /data
fi

# Run whatever the container's main command is
exec "$@"
```

(There is a case where Docker will populate named volumes from image content.  This has some severe limitations: it only works on named volumes and not bind-mounted host directories; it doesn't work on Kubernetes, if that's in your future; if the image content is updated, the volume will not be changed.  Writing out the setup code explicitly at startup will give you more predictable behavior.)